# Any way to limit how often onChange happens in a DateInput? (blueprintjs)

Tags: blueprintjs

We're using the date input component as part of some parameterization on a page. So, as soon as the onChange event fires we want to go fetch some more data.

The problem is that the onChange fires too often as a user is typing. If I type just "Nov" that's setting a valid date of Nov-01-YYYY, and so the onChange event fires. I believe I would like to fire the onChange only when a full date has been entered, or the enter key is pressed, though I'm open to other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

`DateInput` does not currently provide such a feature. Sounds like you're requesting an `onConfirm` handler. GitHub is the place to request features.